# How to solve this type of definite Integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I would like to know how to solve this integral, in particular the first steps:
$$ \int_{-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}}^{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}} \frac{1}{2}x\sin\Bigl(x^2+\frac{\pi}{2}\Bigr)^2dx =?$$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is squared in the integrand? The sine, or its argument?

Comment: What are you concerned about?  The behavior at $x=0$?  Something else?

Comment: An advice: if the limits of integration are $\pm a$ for some a, always be on the lookout for an odd function

Comment: @TeM How can i see that the value is 0 just by the subsitution?

Comment: @lulu i would like to see the substitution step

Comment: PLEASE fix the title (and) the question because the title of the question is very inconsistent with the content of the question. Also, please specify if the argument of sine is squared, or if the whole sine function is squared

Comment: What substitution step?  The integral is obviously $0$ $\textit {unless}$ it diverges at $x=0$.  That's the only thing you need to analyze.

Comment: @TeM  The behavior at $x=0$ is a problem.  Well, it depends on the integrand, which the OP keeps changing.

Comment: @TeM  Right.  I was looking at the header.  The OP should really clarify which one was intended, and what that square refers to (not that it matters, given the symmetry).

Comment: Looks like integrating by parts twice might help. I've not been able to try this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify the integral a little bit:

$$ \int \frac{1}{2}x\sin^{2} \Bigl(x^2+\frac{\pi}{2}\Bigr)dx $$
$$= \frac{1}{2} \int x \cos^{2} \Bigl(x^2\Bigr)dx $$

Substitute $u = x^{2}$, we have:

$$ \frac{1}{4} \int \cos^{2} \Bigl(u\Bigr)du $$

Apply the reduction formula

> $$\int \cos^{n} (u)du = \frac{n-1}{n} \int \cos^{n-2} (u)du + \frac{1}{n} \cos^{n-1} (u) \sin (u)$$

for n=2, we get:

$$ \frac{1}{4} \cdot \left(\frac{\cos (u) \sin (u)}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \int 1du \right)$$
$$= \frac{\cos (u) \sin (u)}{8} + \frac{u}{8} + C$$

Undo substitution:

$$ \frac{\cos (x^{2}) \sin (x^{2})}{8} + \frac{x^{2}}{8} + C$$ 
$$= \frac{\sin (2x^{2}) + 2x^{2}}{16} + C$$

You can now evaluate the definite integral to get the final answer:

$$ \int_{-\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}}^{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}} \frac{1}{2}x\sin^{2} \Bigl(x^2+\frac{\pi}{2}\Bigr)dx = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

This integral vanishes because its integrand is odd and bounded on the integration range, which is finite and symmetric around $0$.